# mysql display each day in a month

Tags: mysql

during a month, display the infor each date, order by date, but this infor is empty in some day. how can i still display each day as a row?

```
Product  date
-----------------
20     2008-01-01
10     2008-01-02
20     2008-01-03
10     2008-01-05
09     2008-01-08
30     2008-01-09
```

result:

```
Product  date
-----------------
20     2008-01-01
10     2008-01-02
20     2008-01-03
0      2008-01-04
10     2008-01-05
0      2008-01-06
0      2008-01-07
09     2008-01-08
30     2008-01-09
```

Comment: I answered this question elsewhere.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16963850/1040437

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, unfortunately, you might have to have a table that contains the dates pre populated to achieve this.

You will have to then left join to this table to retrieve all the appropriate dates.

*In SQL Server 2005+ you could have achieved this using a CTE statement, to recursively generate the dates required.*